# how to border with text and border size cuton left,right,top,botton girdview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to this output

[image: i want to this output (image linked)]

**my dart**

```dart
    Container(
                  height: SizeConfig.blockSizeVertical * 55,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child: GridView(
                      physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                     
                      
                         Container(
                          width: 300,
                          height: 300,
    //BoxDecoration Widget

                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            border: Border.all(
                              color: HexColor.formhex('#c73b08'),
                              width: 20,
                            ),
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                              bottomLeft: const Radius.circular(20.0),
                            ),
                            //Border.all
                            boxShadow: const [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: Colors.black,

                                offset: Offset(
                                  5.0,
                                  5.0,
                                ), //Offset
                                blurRadius: 10.0,
                                spreadRadius: 2.0,
                              ), //BoxShadow
                              BoxShadow(
                                offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
                                blurRadius: 0.0,
                                spreadRadius: 0.0,
                              ), //BoxShadow
                            ],
                          ),

                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Positioned(
                                left: 50,
                                top: 12,
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                      bottom: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  child: const Text(
                                    'Create an account',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black, fontSize: 12),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: Text('reqular'),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                  child: ElevatedButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  primary: HexColor.formhex('#c02801'),
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Select',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: HexColor.formhex('#f7feff'),
                                      fontSize: SizeConfig.safeBlockHorizontal * 4,
                                      decoration: TextDecoration.none),
                                ),
                              )),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 1,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 10,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 10),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
```

how to border with text and border size cuton left,right,top,botton girdview flutter.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Text('TITLE'),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.red,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          ),
          width: 350,
          height: 200,
        ),
        Positioned(
          bottom: 10,
          right: 10,
          left: 10,
          child: Container(
            height: 140,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Text('some text'),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: () {},
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    width: 150,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      'SELECT',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```